# Why can the first term of the Taylor series expansion of $\cos(\theta)$ be written in the way below?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Why can the first term of the Taylor series expansion of $\cos(\theta)$ be written as $\cos(\theta_0) - (\theta - \theta_0) \sin (\theta_0)$?

Comment: In general, the linear Taylor approximation for a function $f(x)$ about $x_0$ is $f_1(x)=f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f'(x_0)$

Comment: You are asking why the derivative of $\cos$ is $-\sin$.

Comment: You are speaking about Taylor, not Mac Laurin

Answer (score 0):

As @lulu said in his comment, the linear approximation or a first order (order $n=1$) Taylor approximation of a function $f$ around $x_0$ is $$f(x)\approx f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f'(x_0),$$
since the [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) is given by
\begin{align}f(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x-x_0)^k}{k!}f^{(k)}(x_0) \\&= f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f'(x_0) + \frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2}f''(x_0) + ... +\frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(x_0)+...\end{align}

Hence, for $\cos (\theta)$, $$\frac{\mathrm{d}\cos (\theta)}{\mathrm{d}\theta} = -\sin (\theta)$$
and, therefore, the Taylor first order approximation around $\theta_0$ is
\begin{align}
\cos (\theta) \approx \cos (\theta_0) + (\theta - \theta_0)(-\sin (\theta)) = \cos (\theta_0) - (\theta - \theta_0)\sin (\theta)
\end{align}